mypy operator "+" not supported for ctypes Structure._fields_
I was handed code that basically describes inheritance via copy pasting all the base fields to every sub struct:
class Base(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("hello", ct.c_int32)
    ]

class Foo(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = Base._fields_ + [
        ("world", ct.c_int64)
    ]

class Bar(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = Base._fields_ + [
        ("joe", ct.c_float)
    ]

# And so on...

Both Foo and Bar have all the fields of Base. But mypy/pyright/pylance's type narrowing hates that the tuples aren't all the same type.
vscode output:

Operator "+" not supported for types "Sequence[tuple[str, type[_CData]] | tuple[str, type[_CData], int]]" and "list[tuple[Literal['world'], type[c_int64]]]" PylancereportOperatorIssue

With minimal changes, how can I make the tools happy?

Changing from + concatenation to embedding * spreading works.
class Foo(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        *Base._fields_,
        ("world", ct.c_int64)
    ]

Using Base as an _anonymous_ field might also be an option
class FooAlt(ct.Structure):
    _anonymous_ = ("base",)
    _fields_ = [
        ("base", Base),
        ("world", ct.c_int64)
    ]


Just do actual inheritance:
import ctypes as ct

class Base(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = ('hello', ct.c_int32),

class Foo(Base):
    _fields_ = ('world', ct.c_int64),

class Bar(Base):
    _fields_ = ('joe', ct.c_float),

f = Foo(1, 2)
print(f.hello, f.world)
b = Bar(3, 4)
print(b.hello, b.joe)

Output:
1 2
3 4.0


What would you do if the "Base" fields were last or in the middle of the structure? (In my case, this might be what the original author should have done though)

@plswork04 In that case, declare the base as an embedded structure, e.g. _fields_ = ('a', c_int), ('base', Base), or use _anonymous_.  I'd follow whatever the C structure looked like that was being wrapped.
